# Why does the firestore not remove the bytes stored and objects when deleting all documents and collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Hi I am developing with FireBase firestore.

Every document I write I use the admin panel to delete all documents and subcollections as stated in the popup when you try to delete all.

However, I don't see ever the storage going down. It only goes up after deletes etc.

Moreover, although I do not have a staging environment only a normal one I can see that the consumption mainly comes from there as seen in the screenshot below...

[image]

So in short, even I delete all documents + subcollections the store bytes do not decrease.

PS. Same happens even if I use my own app to do a delete for all documents and subcollections

UPDATE:

Todays usage 
[image]

Cloud storage 
[image]

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: This is a screenshot of metrics for Cloud Storage, which is a product and a different thing than Cloud Firestore.

Comment: No that is not true. If you see it states objects and my cloud storage is empty / never used . this number increases when I write to fire store not on cloud storage. Or if you are correct then this is a big mess up.

Comment: I am not seeing anything in your question or image showing your Cloud Storage is empty. Secondly, to get that graph, in the Firebase Console you MUST click the *Storage* option on the left and then select the Usage tab - it shows 61.4MB stored. To see what the details are for a a *Cloud Firestore* project you have to select that project, then select Database on the left, then select the *Usage* tab. That will take you to a totally different site; Google Cloud Platform which will show a list like *Cloud Firestore Read Operations* and *Cloud Firestore Stored Data*. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Jay My cloud storage is empty. I am updating the question. 
The storage usage shows a number of objects, I have never used cloud storage so the only thing i could relate to is the cloudstore. I understand I go to another palce when I see firestore usage but as you understand this is a bit crazy (cloud storage reporting cloud store usage)

Comment: @Jay I have updated the question, I think I understand what you mean, but then I have a wild guess why this is happening. Those must be my app deployement files at google app engine. this is super confusing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion here (which I'll talk to the FirebaseUI team about) is the first graph is showing you the GCS bucket staging.quant.appspot.com has ~61MB of data stored in it. The last image in your question shows that the GCS bucket used for Firebase is empty. The key takeaway here is you have 2 GCS buckets, the Firebase used one is empty, the 'staging' one is not.

The staging bucket is generally used by App Engine as part of the upload process for apps, which is why it probably has data in it even though you aren't using Cloud Storage via Firebase.

I am the product manager on Cloud Firestore, so I can guarantee this is showing 'Cloud Storage' (GCS) not 'Storage used by Cloud Firestore'.

Comment: That is what I suspected when I finally related to the size increase by deployments (which if you understand I only had a few). (see my last comment on my question). 

Thanks a lot for the time to answer and look at this.

Comment: I am at 10gbs can we get a clear answer as to what we can delete? I have artifacts/containers/images from 3 years ago occupying significant space. I want to delete them but i am unsure of the implications